# How should I determine degrees of freedom for t-test in ordinal regression?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, degrees-of-freedom, polr

I consider a proportional odds (ordinal regression) model, as described in Agresti (2002) and estimated by `R` `base` package function `MASS`. The software reports t-values but no p-values in `summary`. I wonder how I should determine the degrees of freedom for the t-test. In simple linear regression $df=n-2$ where $n$ the sample size. Is this also the case for ordinal linear regression?

Comment: Why not extract the residual df from the object? And I think polr is in MASS not base.

Comment: Are you sure residual df is the correct df for the t-test?